Other ways to connect to Oracle DB through sqldeveloper?
anyone here aware of any other ways to connect to Oracle DB apart from the below mentioned ones?
1- user id and password.
2- proxy user connection / Kerberos connection.
different ways to connect to DB through sqldeveloper.

May I ask why you are asking?

what is the way that you WANT to login to your database

I am trying to connect to DB through sql developer. But don’t want to connect using the above mentioned methods and restrict access.
User id and password - unreliable as if any of the team members updated and password and doesn’t update the sheet then issue in connecting to DB.

Kerberos- if someone shares the keytab file with other teams, they will be able to access DB which I am trying to restrict

kerberos is supported
